# No such file or directory ssh-add ~/id_rsa

Tags: git, github

I am trying to add my ssh key to my ssh agent.Can i do it if my ssh key is in my external hard drive.I want to clone my repositories in my hard drive

Comment: Did you solve this? Getting same issue

Answer (score 1):

you should use `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` instead .i think your path is incorrect the key pair are under ~/.ssh folder and not ~/

Comment: It still says that their is no file or directory

Comment: Have you generated the ssh key first? are you sure the file exist? do you know the exact path to the generated key? are you on linux ,macOS or windows .i have to know these in order to help you

Comment: I have windows 10.My path is D:\Git\.ssh.Yes i have generated my ssh key via PuTTyGen and yes the file exist.

Comment: You should the use ssh-add D:\Git\.ssh\id_rsa .you were using the wrong path .The path ~./ssh is for Unix like systems

Comment: I still have that message.Also my current directory is where the key is if that helps.

Comment: Try ssh-add id_rsa ,also attach a screenshot of the error please

Comment: It displayed the same thing. Here is the image https://imgur.com/5tnvbQ0.

Comment: add file extension id_rsa.ppk